# how to put the strings without split

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to fetch the list of channels from sqlite3 database.

When I fetch the list of channels to set each channel in each label control `4010`, `4011`, `4012`, `4013`, `4014`, `4015` and `4016`, it will split the strings into each letter which it will put each string `1`, `0`, `1`, `A`, `B`, `C` in each label control.

What I want to achieve is to get the list of channels to set each channel in each label control without split the strings.

When I use this:

```
#Pull the data from the database
channelList = list()
programList = list()
database_path = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))

if os.path.exists(database_path):
    #get the channels list
    cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel')


    for row in cur:
        channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
        channelList.append(channel)

        # set the channels text
        for index in range(0, channels_per_page):
            self.getControl(4110 + index).setLabel(channels[index])
```

**Here is the list of channels when I print it:**

```
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 102 CBS
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 105 ESPN USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 106 Fox News
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 107 Animal Planet
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 110 SPIKE
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 111 BRAVO USA
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 112 BRAVO1
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 113 BRAVO2
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 114 BRAVO3
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 115 BRAVO4
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 116 BRAVO5
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 117 BRAVO6
17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 118 BRAVO7
```

I want to set the text in each label control like this:

```
>>4010 ABC FAMILY
>>4011 CNN USA
>>4012 ESPN USA
>>4013 Fox News
>>4014 Animal Planet
>>4015 USA Network
>>4016 SPIKE
```

**Here is the result:**

```
4110 >> 1
4111 >> 0
4112 >> 1
4113 >> 
4114 >> A
4115 >> B
4116 >> C
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? You use `channels[index]`, but `channels` is never defined.

Comment: I have to ask, because you're asking tons of questions about this project: how long do you spend attempting to fix a bug before posting here? Also your code is exactly the same as it was in your previous question, did you change it based on feedback at all?

Comment: You want 4010 but you start the count at 4110? Is that a typo? Or what do you mean by this?

Comment: @EugeneK yes i want to start the count at 4110 to 4116 with 7 list of channels.

Comment: @Kevin how i can count the list of channels for each array when i set each channel in each label control?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense this is a different question from my previous post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be a scary word, but `regex` is perfect for this.

```
import re
index = 4110
# Assuming there a line that is for example 17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
regexString = '\S+ \s+ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s+ (?P<show>.*)'
regex       = re.compile(regexString, re.X)
for line in lines:
    match = regex.match(line)
    print index, match.group('show')
    index += 1
```

Comment: @user3757279 SO is not a code writing service. We will answer questions, but we won't do all the work for you. You absolutely need to learn to debug, because it's way faster than asking SO about every bug you have.

Comment: Well....assuming channelList contains stuff like `17:02:10 T:6400  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY`, just change `for line in lines` to `for item in channelList`